# Elastic search find exact string PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm new to `elasticsearch`, however I'm facing difficulties as my queries doesn't change my results upon changing the types and filters!

I'm working with MongoDB PHP, and here's my code:

```
  $test2 = [ 
        "filtered" => [
            "query" => [
                "match_phrase" => [
                    "product_name" => [
        "query" =>  "Brown Fox",
    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
$testResult = $client_es->search(
                array(
                    'index' =>'myindex',
                    'type'  => 'mytype',
                    'body'  => array(
                        'query' => $test2,
                        'size' => 5000,
                    ),
                )
            );


        $testR = $testResult["hits"]["hits"];
        $total = $testResult["hits"]["total"];
        echo "TOTAL:  ". $total ."<br>";

        foreach ($testR as $key ) {
            echo $key["_source"]["product_name"];
           echo "<br>";


        }
```

I want to search the exact matches only, but Im getting all the stuff that had the string. 
Guide me in steps how to solve this problem.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
curl -XPUT "www.domain.com/my_index/my_mapping/my_type" -d '{
        "my_type" : {
          "properties": {
              "product_name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
          }
        }
}'; echo
```

Comment: I'm not sure if PHP has a specific implementation of ES that requires additional or different syntax (as NEST does for C#) but if you are looking for an exact match, in this case I would suggest a Term Filter on a filtered query with a matchAll.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really follow your code from your headline. If your problem is that you don't get exact-match results, it's probably the case that the mapping of the respective `string` field is not using `not_analyzed`, for example

```
{
    "product": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

instead of

```
{
    "product": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will cause the `name` field to be indexed with the default analyser (causing each word to be indexed).

See

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2

Comment: When I added this by SSH, it says `acknowledged = true` but I cann't use this.

Comment: What should "I can't use this" mean?

Comment: When I add my index and my type in search query, as mentioned in my code above, I couldn't find any results.

Comment: `curl -XPUT "www.domain.com/my_index/my_mapping/my_type" ...` should be `curl -XPUT "www.domain.com/my_index/my_type/_mapping" ...` It's very possible that you have to reindex your data after changing the mapping. Have you checked that there are any documents in the index/type? Please refer to the ElasticSearch docs!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
    <?php
$search_host = '127.0.0.1';
$search_port = '9200';
$index = 'myindex';
$doc_type = 'tweecoms';
$query = '_search';
ini_set('memory_limit', '5500000M');
set_time_limit(10000);
echo date('j m y h:i:s') . '<br>';
    $json_doc = 
                 '{
                    "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*life*",
                        "lenient": true
                    }
                    },
                    "size": 1000,
                    "from": 0,
                    "fields": [
                    "association_key"
                    ]
                }';
    //$json_doc = json_encode($json_doc);
    $baseUri = 'http://' . $search_host . ':' . $search_port . '/' . $index . '/' . $doc_type . '/' . $query;
    $ci = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $baseUri);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_PORT, $search_port);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_doc);
    $response = curl_exec($ci);
    curl_close($ci);
    print_r($response);
    echo '<br>'.date('j m y h:i:s') . '<br>';
```